# viewWillAppear not being called after popToRootViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller, viewcontroller-lifecyle

This is the flow:

`VC1` ->(PUSH)-> `VC2` ->(PUSH) -> `VC3`

When clicking a button in `VC3` I am calling the method below and it works properly - taking me back to `VC1`:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

But the problem is in `viewWillAppear()` method in `VC1` which is not being called.
Is there any solution to call it?

Answer (score 0):

i am not exactly sure but `viewWillAppear()` will called while loading controller. it's not calling while dismiss other controller.so, you need to try `custom Delegate` or `Notification observer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick here:

```swift
if let root = navigationController?.viewControllers.last(where: { $0 is YourRootController }) {
     navigationController?.popToViewController(root, animated: true)
}
```